# How to redirect parallel pipes in bash?

Tags: bash

This doesn't work:

```
   $ head file | tee >(sort >&3) | paste <(cat <&3) -
   bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

but I hope it's obvious what it's intended to do, the equivalent of:

```
   $ head file | sort >temp1
   $ head file >temp2
   $ paste temp1 temp2
```

What is the proper way to create and use that parallel pipe?

(Assume "head" represents an expensive operation, and I'm aware of the dangers of deadlock.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piping with Process substitution and joining output again](https://superuser.com/questions/1194044/piping-with-process-substitution-and-joining-output-again)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that explicitly creating another pipe first does what I wanted to do:

```
$ pipe3="$$.pipe3"
$ mkfifo $pipe3
...
$ head file_1 | tee >(sort >$pipe3) | (sleep 1; paste <(cat <$pipe3) - )
...
$ tail file_2 | tee >(sort -r >$pipe3) | (sleep 1; paste <(cat <$pipe3) - )
...
$ rm $pipe3
```

The need for "sleep", and using "$pipe3" rather than "&3", makes it a bit less elegant though.