# How to split and join parallel pipes?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, parallel-processing

I'd like to pipe the output of 1 command into multiple pipes and pipe outputs from multiple commands into 1 single command.

An example of `split`:

```
# Single output to multiple pipes
echo "This is a sentence" | split | cut -d ' ' -f 1,3 > file1.txt
                                  | cut -d ' ' -f 2,4 > file2.txt
```

In the above example of `split`, the output `"This is a sentence"` is split piped into 2 `cut`s and 2 different files.

An example of `join`:

```
Hello(){
   echo "Hello $1 and $2"
}

echo "Alice" | 
echo "Bob"   | join | Hello
# output: "Hello Alice and Bob"
```

In the above example of `join` takes the outputs from 2 different pipes and give them to the function `Hello` as 2 piped inputs.

An example of `split` and `join` used together:

```
# split the input into multiple pipes
echo "Alice Bob Charlie Dave" | split

# 2 separate split pipes are processed and then joined into a single pipe
split | cut -d ' ' -f 1,3 | join
split | cut -d ' ' -f 2,4 | join

Hello(){
   echo "$1 loves $2"
}

join | Hello

# Output:
# Alice Charlie loves Bob Dave
```

The above example implements both `split` and `join` to have multiple pipes processed in parallel. `split` is "single input, multiple outputs", `join` is "multiple inputs, single output".

What's the best way to implement the demonstrated `split` and `join` in a shell/bash script?

Comment: Some general ideas: [here](https://superuser.com/q/1194044/432690).

Answer (score 1):

You may use GNU Parallel for split:

```
echo "This is a sentence" |
  parallel --tee --pipe -q cut -d ' ' -f {} ::: 1,3 2,4

echo "This is a sentence" |
  parallel --tee --pipe "cut -d ' ' -f {} >file{#}" ::: 1,3 2,4
```

Comment: There are multiple implementations of `parallel`. Which is this one? On Ubuntu the default `parallel` from `moreutils` does not have the `--tee` or `--pipe` options.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong GNU

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `tee`, or in this case likely better use `awk`, `perl` etc.

Or to be wonky ...

```sh
echo "Jane Bob Alice Joe" |
(tee >(
  cut -d ' ' -f1,3 -z >&2 && printf ' loves ' >&2) |
  cut -d ' ' -f2,4
) 2>&1 | 
tr -d '\0'
```

> Jane Alice loves Bob Joe

## Split

Split using `tee` + process substitution / subshell.

```sh
echo "This is a sentence" | 
tee >(cut -d ' ' -f1,3 >file1.txt) | 
cut -d ' ' -f2,4 >file2.txt

# ...

echo "This is a sentence with some more words" |
tee \
    >(cut -d ' ' -f1,3 >file1.txt) \
    >(cut -d ' ' -f2,4 >file2.txt) \
    >(cut -d ' ' -f3,5 >file3.txt) \
    >(cut -d ...
```

But with for example `awk` we can do more *logic* whilst also keeping the processes and parsing down.

```sh
awk '{ 
    print $1,$3 > "file1.txt"
    print $2,$4 > "file2.txt"
}'

# ... arbitrary length of input:

awk '{
    for (i = 1; i < NF - 1; ++i)
        print $i, $(i + 2)  > sprintf("file%02d.txt", i)
}'
```

## Join

As for `join` it is a bit unclear what the goal really is. Some variants:

Starting out with:

```sh
#! /bin/bash -
awk '{
    for (i = 1; i < NF - 1; ++i)
        print $i, $(i + 2)  > sprintf("file%02d.txt", i)
}'
```

... or simply

```
#! /bin/awk -f
{
    for (i = 1; i < NF - 1; ++i)
        print $i, $(i + 2)  > sprintf("file%02d.txt", i)
}
```

```
$ ./splitinput <<<"Alice Jim Jane Carl An Fred Adler Morgan"
$ tail file0*
==> file01.txt <==
Alice Jane

==> file02.txt <==
Jim Carl

==> file03.txt <==
Jane An

==> file04.txt <==
Carl Fred

==> file05.txt <==
An Adler

==> file06.txt <==
Fred Morgan
```

- Using `paste`:

```sh
$ paste -d ' ' file01.txt <(echo loves) file02.txt
Alice Jane loves Jim Carl
```

- Using `bash` read single shot:

```sh
hello() {
    printf '%s loves %s\n' "$1" "$2"
}
IFS= read -r name1<"$1"
IFS= read -r name2<"$2"
hello "$name1" "$name2"
```

`./script file01.txt file02.txt`

### Multi set operation

- Using `bash` read in combination with `cat`:

```sh
names=()
while IFS= read -r name; do
    names+=("$name")
done< <(cat $@)

# Which can be simplified as:
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a names< <(cat file*)
```

Gives an array of names to work with:

```sh
printf '# Name: %s\n' "${names[@]}"
# Name: Alice Jane
# Name: Jim Carl
# Name: Jane An
# Name: Carl Fred
# Name: An Adler
# Name: Fred Morgan
```

```sh
printf ';; bash for\n'
for ((i = 0; i < ${#names[@]}; i += 2)) do
    hello "${names[@]:i:i+2}"
done
```

Using a loop to process all files with `read`:

```
printf ';; bash while argv\n'
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    IFS= read -r name1<"$1"
    shift
    IFS= read -r name2<"$1"
    shift
    hello "$name1" "$name2"
done
```

Using `awk` to process all files:

```sh
printf ';; awk\n'
awk -v adv=loves '
{
    if (NR % 2)
        name=$0
    else
        print name,adv,$0
}' "$@"
```

---

```
Alice Jane loves Jim Carl
Jane An loves Carl Fred
An Adler loves Fred Morgan
```

---

Or, to get fancy.

```
hello2() {
    fmt -uw32 <<-EOH
    $1 loves $2, $2 loves $3 and $3 loves $2.

    $5 is in love with $4 and $6 is all alone,
    but has a secret crush on both $1 and $3.
    EOH
}
hello2 "${names[@]}"
```

```
Alice Jane loves Jim Carl, Jim
Carl loves Jane An and Jane An
loves Jim Carl.

An Adler is in love with Carl
Fred and Fred Morgan is all
alone, but has a secret crush
on both Alice Jane and Jane An.
```