# Bash split stream (tee) and join them together

Tags: bash, pipe, tee, join, pipelining

I need to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255841/how-can-i-split-and-re-join-stdout-from-multiple-processes), except that in that question the OP just concat the outputs of `command2` and `command3`, and I need them be handed over separately, like this:

```
             command2 [stream A]
            /                    \
    command1                      join -j1 [stream A] [stream B]
            \                    /
             command3 [stream B]
```

(here, `join` is the coreutils `join` utility, the only one I've named explicitely to make it clear that I don't want the streams A and B to be merged indiscriminately)

I've tried this:

`command1 | tee >(command2 >&3- ) >(command3 >&4- ) >/dev/null | join -j1 /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4`

But bash rightfully complains:

```
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
bash: 4: Bad file descriptor
```

(because file descriptors 3 and 4 are not open yet)

I think I need instruct bash to somehow call 2 extra `pipe(2)`  (like it does when piping `fd1` from left command to `fd0` of right command in `left | right`). As each call of such `pipe(2)` creates two fds (one for writing and other for reading), I need to:

- for `command2` close the reading end, and redirect stdout to the writing end (of pipe1);
- for `command3` close the reading end, and redirect stdout to the writing end (of pipe2);
- for `join` close both writing ends and instruct it to open `/dev/fd/reading-end-of-pipe1` and `/dev/fd/reading-end-of-pipe2`

I don't necessarily have write access to any path in this enviroment, precluding the use of `mkfifo`.

Comment: With `mkfifo` it would be something like the contraption in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1194059/432690). Really no `/tmp` nor anything?

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can do this with a [coprocess](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270/108618). Either I'm too dumb, or managing descriptors like `${COPROC[1]}` (so they are available where I want them and closed where and when I want them to be closed) is really cumbersome. I tried this and I failed. I found a less cumbersome way, but it requires `/proc`.

The version of my Bash is 5.0.3.

It's relatively easy to use `coproc` just to set relevant pipes and then use `/proc/…/fd/…` where needed.

1. Start a coprocess:

   ```
   coproc command2
   ```
2. Build the rest of the piping. There's a quirk. I expect `command2` to be a filter that exits only after its stdin or stdout is closed. The shell holds these open and if we detach then the coprocess will be terminated. So we cannot detach until we attach processes that are going to really use the coprocess. On the other hand if the shell does not detach then the coprocess will not terminate and other processes will probably wait for it. This means we must run them asynchronously with the shell and detach the shell later, otherwise the whole setup may block. Build the rest of the piping and run it asynchronously:

   ```
   command1 | tee "/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/0" | command3 | join -j1 - "/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/1" &
   ```
3. Detach the shell from the coprocess. In my tests it was enough to close the descriptor with a number available as `${COPROC[1]}`. This is how you do it:

   ```
   exec {COPROC[1]}>&-
   ```

   <sup>Note the above syntax does not really use `${COPROC[1]}` with `$`. Quite unintuitive. Before you close the descriptor you can see the number: `echo "${COPROC[1]}"`. Suppose it prints `60`. `exec 60>&-` is a valid command, but don't try to `exec "${COPROC[1]}">&-`. The latter syntax will "work" like `exec 60 >&-` and it will close the stdout of the shell!</sup>
4. Now you can `wait` for our pipeline; or you can `fg` it if job control is enabled.

Notes:

- If job control is enabled (it is by default in interactive Bash) and `command1` wants to read something from the terminal then it won't be able to until you `fg` it. It's different when job control is disabled, e.g. in a script. If job control is disabled then some shells would redirect the stdin of `command1` to `/dev/null` or some equivalent file. This is how `&` works. Bash doesn't do this for pipelines though.
- Unfortunately there is a race condition: `exec {COPROC[1]}>&-` may be executed and the coprocess terminated before our asynchronous commands manage to open `/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/…`. A non-elegant "fix" is to `sleep` a while. I don't like this very much (in theory a delay does not guarantee anything, it just reduces the probability of failure). A robust fix is to open the pipes in a subshell that is going to `exec` to a command that opens `…/fd/0` anyway, then signal the main shell it's safe for it to close the descriptor.

  ```bash
  coproc command2
  trap 'exec {COPROC[1]}>&-' USR1
  command1 | ( exec 3>"/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/0" 4<"/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/1"; kill -s USR1 "$$"; exec tee "/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/0" ) | command3 | join -j1 - "/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/1" &
  wait
  wait
  ```

  We need two `wait`s because the first `wait` will probably be interrupted by the signal.

---

#### Proof of concept

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set +m   # job control explicitly disabled
coproc sed 's/$/ added_by_sed/'
trap 'exec {COPROC[1]}>&-' USR1
echo 'Type few lines and press Ctrl+d (twice if needed).'
cat -n | ( exec 3>"/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/0" 4<"/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/1"; kill -s USR1 "$$"; exec tee "/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/0" ) | awk '{print $0,"added_by_awk"}' | join -j1 - "/proc/$COPROC_PID/fd/1" &
wait
wait
```